# Requests Forcing Header

Tags: python, python-requests

I am currently using the requests library to pass in a header.

I believe the documentation states that certain events take precedence over custom headers.

Is there a way to have your custom header take precedence?

For example, I want a `content-type` of `'application/vnd.reviewboard.org.diff.data+json'`.

However, the response continues to suggest a different header:

```
requests.get('url_here', headers={'content-type':'application/vnd.reviewboard.org.diff.data+json'}).__dict__
```

will return

```
'content-type': 'application/vnd.reviewboard.org.file+json'
```

If relevant, I am trying to hit a Review Board endpoint at

https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/2.5/webapi/2.0/resources/file-diff/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to specify the content type that you will receive in the response, not the content type of your request. So you should use the `Accept` header, not `content-type`.